# How to move Django password/secret key to Windows Vault/credentials?

Tags: django, windows

I have a web app developed in Django. The password and the secret key are visible inn settings.py file. I would like to hide them or store them somewhere to read it into Django. One option is Windows credentials. How can I connect the windows vault to Django? Or is there any better --more secure way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use an environment variable, otherwise if you must, create a new python file that inherits the existing settings in `settings.py`, i.e. `from core.settings import *`, and then add `secret key = x` and `password = y` in the new file. Then run using `python3 manage.py runserver --settings=core.new_settings`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to take it from windows vault

Answer (score 0):

I use keyring to do this. It's super easy to setup and use in your settings.py

https://github.com/jaraco/keyring

Store your credentials in credential manager as a generic credential then you can call it by matching the name you gave the credential and the user name. For Example

[image]

```
DBKEYRING = keyring.get_credential("Database Account","admin")
DBUSER = DBKEYRING.username
DBPASS = DBKEYRING.password
```